# find all points within a range to any point of an other set

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, knn

I have two sets of points **A** and **B**.

I want to find all points in **B** that are within a certain range **r** to **A**, where a point **b** in **B** is said to be within range **r** to **A** if there is at least one point **a** in **A** whose (Euclidean) distance to **b** is equal or smaller to r.

Each of the both sets of points is a coherent set of points. They are generated from the voxel locations of two non overlapping objects.

In 1D this problem fairly easy: all points of **B** within [min(**A**)-**r** max(**A**)+**r**]

But I am in 3D.

What is the best way to do this?

I currently repetitively search for every point in **A** all points in **B** that within range using some knn algorithm (ie. matlab's rangesearch) and then unite all those sets. But I got a feeling that there should be a better way to do this. I'd prefer a high level/vectorized solution in matlab, but pseudo code is fine too :)

I also thought of writing all the points to images and using image dilation on object A with a radius of r. But that sounds like quite an overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [**k-d tree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to store all points of A.

Iterate points b of B, and for each point - [find the nearest point in A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search) (let it be a) in the k-d tree. The point b should be included in the result if and only if the distance `d(a,b)` is smaller then `r`.

Complexity will be `O(|B| * log(|A|) + |A|*log(|A|))`

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for. It reduces the run time per case from 46s to 10s.

Comment: @YAK is it possible to share the code of doing this as I really need it?

Comment: @user1460166 there you go

Answer (score 2):

I archived further speedup by enhancing @amit's solution by first filtering out points of **B** that are definitely too far away from all points in **A**, because they are too far away even in a single dimension (kinda following the 1D solution mentioned in the question).

Doing so limits the complexity to `O(|B|+min(|B|,(2r/res)^3) * log(|A|) + |A|*log(|A|))` where `res` is the minimum distance between two points and thus reduces run time in the test case to 5s (from 10s, and even more in other cases).

example code in matlab:

```
r=5;
A=randn(10,3);
B=randn(200,3)+5;

roughframe=[min(A,[],1)-r;max(A,[],1)+r];

sortedout=any(bsxfun(@lt,B,roughframe(1,:)),2)|any(bsxfun(@gt,B,roughframe(2,:)),2);
B=B(~sortedout,:);
[~,dist]=knnsearch(A,B);
B=B(dist<=r,:);
```

Answer (score 0):

`bsxfun()` is your friend here. So, say you have 10 points in set **A** and 3 points in set **B**. You want to have them arrange so that the singleton dimension is at the row / columns. I will randomly generate them for demonstration

```
A = rand(10, 1, 3);                    % 10 points in x, y, z, singleton in rows
B = rand(1, 3, 3);                     %  3 points in x, y, z, singleton in cols
```

Then, distances among all the points can be calculated in two steps

```
dd = bsxfun(@(x,y) (x - y).^2, A, B);  % differences of x, y, z in squares
d = sqrt(sum(dd, 3));                  % this completes sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)
```

Now, you have an array of the distance among points in **A** and **B**. So, for exampl, the distance between point 3 in **A** and point 2 in **B** should be in  `d(3, 2)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I thought about that too, but it scales with O(|A| * |B|) so I assume it runs slower. But I'll test and report.

Comment: It does. (needs 61s). Anyway, bsxfun is really powerful tool for ml users, thanks for mentioning it. But accumarray, sort and obv. knnsearch can give a much higher (because algorithmic) speedup.

Comment: @YAK I See the kdtree answer above and it is great. I learned something new today.  Thanks for the good question!